# SpringMVC RESTful push and pull implementations

Tags: java, jquery, json, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am familiar with pull type implementation where my jQuery will issue ajax calls to my REST url over timed intervals. I am looking for solution/example on how to implement 'PUSH' type implementation where Server will push updates to client whenever update is available. It would something like Blocking on queue i.e. web client will go to wait state instead of consistently sending requests to server for requesting updates.

Comment: thats called web sockets http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Comment: looks like solution, i will try it.